# Replace backslashes with forward slashes in filenames in Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform

If the OS is Windows, and I get a `fileName` from the OS, for example in `File.listFiles()`, I get backslashes. I need to *mange* these to forward slashes if  want to include the filename in a message `String`.  Using a `replaceAll("\\","/")` works fine, but is it dangerous or risky to do it unconditionally?  I am developing on Windows and I want this code to be able to run on other platforms.

Comment: What do you mean is it "dangerous or risky"?  There is nothing wrong with what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) field is set to the system-specific `String` that represents the proper slash on your file system. If you know that the incoming string always has backslashes, and you need a system-specific slash, then you can use

```
replaceAll("\\", File.separator)
```

On Windows, this would produce the original string, while on Mac and Unix it would produce a string with forward slashes instead of backslashes.